# Biq-query: add new key:val in json

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I add a new key/val pair in an already existing JSON col in bigqyery using SQL (big query flavor).

[image]

To something like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery provides Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements such as the SQL Update statement.  See:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement

What you will have to do is retrieve the original value of your structured column and then perform a SQL UPDATE statement to set the new value of the column to be the absolute new value that you want.

Take care to realize that BigQuery is an OLAP database and is optimized for queries rather that updates or deletes.  Make sure you read the information on using DML statements in BigQuery found here.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this question is less about how to update the table, but more about how to adjust existing json with extra/new key:value (then to either update table or just simply select out)

So, I assume you have table like below

[image]

and you might have another table with those new key:value pairs to use

[image]

in case if you don't really have second table - you can just use CTE like below

```
with new_key_val as (
  select 1 id, '{"key3":"value3"}' add_json union all
  select 2 id, '{"key14":"value14"}' 
)
```

So, having above - you can use below approach

```
select *,
  ( select '{' || string_agg(trim(kv)) || ',' || trim(add_json, '{}') || '}'
    from unnest(split(trim(json_col, '{}'), ',')) kv
  ) adjusted_json
from your_table
left join new_key_val
using(id)
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery supports JSON as a native data type but only offers a limited set of  [JSON functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions). Unless your json data has a pre-defined, simple schema with known keys, you probably want to go the string-manipulation way.